# Multiple name parameters with default values in Ruby 2.5

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method where I need to pass multiple name parameters with default values but I am getting `syntax error, unexpected keyword_next` error. How can I rectify it?

**Eg method**

```
def action(prev = nil, next = nil)
  if prev.present?
    # do something
  elsif next.present?
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

How can I make the above code work?

Comment: I think If you would have used the Tag ``ruby`` instead of ``ruby-2.5`` you would have gotten an answer much faster. This is not related to a concreted Ruby version. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` is a reserved word in Ruby, as it is used to skip one iteration in enumerables. For example in the following code:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_array.each do |number|
  next if number == 2
  puts number
end
```

which will oputput:

```
1
3
4
```

This means that you can not use it as a variable/parameter name. To fix your code, you just need to rename the variable. For example:

```
def action(prev = nil, following = nil)
  if prev.present?
    # do something
  elsif following.present?
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```